# Constructing geodetic lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, geodetic

[image: This is were I'm at]

I am trying to construct a geodetic line between destinations. I have followed two guides without luck. This are the steps I've done:

1. I created a polyline shapefile and named it "Distance"
2. I went to advanced editing a pressed "construct geodetic"
3. Now there should be a template called "Distance" to choose but as you can see in the picture it isn't there.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but what happens if you click on the Template button? Is anything listed?

Comment: Yes, rivers is listed if i mark it in the table of contents.